# Identifying DSN (Delivery Status Notifications) or NDR (Non Delivery Reports) and the failed recipients in Microsoft Graph / Outlook REST API

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I found several questions here about detecting mail status in various mail servers, but still it's unclear how to do it using Outlook REST API.

[In documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) we can see the response for request:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkADhMGAAA=
```

But it seems like the answer doesn't have a field, which contains such information. I also looked into request for headers:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages?$select=subject,internetMessageHeaders
```

Unfortunately, there was no header like `X-Failed-Recipients`.

Are there any ways to get delivery status and/or failed recipients using Outlook API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My approach to this was getting message details and the internetMessageHeaders as you have done.

- First I check for header `Content-Type` value `multipart/report`
  which denotes a DSN (delivery status notification), see [RFC
  3461](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3461).

  - `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/<id>?$select=internetMessageHeaders`
- Then I get the `toRecipients` property of the message which contains the
  email address of the recipient that failed.

  - `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/<id>`

*Note:*

- Not all mail servers follow RFC3461, so some DSN/NDR emails may slip through
- I could not find any documentation saying that `toRecipients` always contains the value of the failed recipient, but so far I have yet to find an example to the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

I did try the mention [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54575451/7545969), but It worked when I add extra '/'
in the link

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/<id>/?$select=internetMessageHeaders
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).