# How to verify if an email is NDR using Microsoft.Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to identify if an Email is NDR or not.
Using Microsoft.Graph, I trying to copy some emails from an email address to an external database. Because it could be the possibility to have emails that told me a specific email couldn't be delivered because of some reason, I want to skip them. I already check the properties of Message object, but I couldn't find something to help me in order to identify if that email is NDR or not. I am expecting to have a special flag or something like that.

This is how I retrieve all the emails from the email address:

```
var email = _graphServiceClient.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages
                 .Request()
                 .Filter("isRead ne true")
                 .GetAsync().Result;
```

Any advice could help. Thank you in advance.

SOLUTION:
I have used "multipart/report" from "internetMessageHeaders" as you will see in the discussions bellow.

Comment: You need to access the InternetMessageHeaders.

Comment: Ok. I already did and I received new extra data. Some data is as follow:   ```Name  "Content-Type"
   ODataType "microsoft.graph.internetMessageHeader"
  Value  "multipart/report"``` Is this what I need? "multipart/report"?

Comment: Yes, I think so - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53606537/identifying-dsn-delivery-status-notifications-or-ndr-non-delivery-reports-an

Comment: It should work. Thank you!

Comment: I tested the above it works for me too!!

Comment: @stuard your approach worked. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear... its better you can move this to answer... so it can be useful to others as well @dumitrualin